# "I wanted you to know that ..." is it mean or offensive

Tags: grammar, american-english

I am not a native English speaker. I am writing an email to my boss and I want him to know an important thing, so will it be ok to say "I wanted you to know that ...", it is offensive/mean etc in any sense ?

Comment: Given that the context is "writing an email to my boss", one more polite way is "I would like to inform you that ...".

Comment: @DamkerngT. how do you see "I wanted you to know that ...", because I had to send email quickly which i did

Comment: It _can_ be used in a rather abrasive and uncouth manner; but it can also easily be perfectly neutral. Since presumably your boss is aware that you are not a native speaker, I would expect him to give you the benefit of the doubt. Without knowing what the rest of the sentence says, there's no way of saying whether it comes off as too rash or not. It is certainly not an offensive or mean phrase in and of itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find it offensive or mean. If you wanted to soften the language somewhat, though, you could use:

> *I wanted to **let** you know that ...*

NOAD defines that idiomatic phrase as:

> **let someone know** inform someone

You could also avoid the use of the word *you* by saying:

> *I just wanted to say that...*

which often implies that you are simply passing some information along.

Answer (score 1):

You can also say "I thought you should know that...", which can mean either:

- "I think that you will benefit, if you know that...", or
- "I think it would be good for you (or everyone) if you knew that...", which suggests that it will be bad for them (or everyone) if they do not know.

This is useful for delicate situations where you do not want to cause offense, but you believe that some action that is important is not being taken when it should be, or that some action is being taken *when it should not be*.

If there is not concern about an action, then you can say: "It may be helpful for you to know that...". This suggests that it will assist them in making a decision, or understanding a situation.

If you have a recommendation, you can say, "Can (or may) I suggest that you consider (action)...?" and then follow it with a ***brief*** point about why the recommendation may be helpful.

When doing this, in most cases you will want to avoid appearing to be too directing. So, such a recommendation can be softened with other comments such as "From the little (information) I've (been able to gather/seen/been told)...", and "I could be wrong, but...", and "Just from an outsider's point of view...", etc.

If you are concerned that they may not be receptive to your attempt to offer anything, you can ask, "Would it be alright if I made a suggestion?" or, "...an observation?"  They can then refuse, or accept. If they refuse, keep in mind that they may think you are unqualified to comment, or they may believe they have sufficient information or opinions already, and do not be discouraged.  A good leader will decline politely. A very good leader will also encourage you to offer your opinion again in the future, when the timing/situation/topic may be more suitable.